# Jira-Python Update Epic Link

Tags: jira, python-jira

I am writing a script that automatically sets properties of issues in JIRA. I am able to set just about any field for an issue except for the epic link after the issue already has one. The following line returns a 500 error:

issue.update(customfield_10006 = epic)

where epic is the name of an existing epic link. Is there a way for me to remove the existing epic link or somehow update it without causing an internal server error?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Are you sure it is just that single line?!

Comment: It is that single line that's causing me trouble. The program works when I don't mess with the epic link.

Answer (score 0):

I got this one working when updating existing issue Epic link (tnx to https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/update-epic-link-via-rest-api-779158615.html )

issue.update(fields={'customfield_10006': str(TARGETEPIC)})

as my TARGETEPIC was an "issue object thingy" had to convert it to normal string (like ABC-123). Using 'ABC-123' worked directly